# How to have arrows for moving the cursor right and left when writing text on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, text, text-input

On an iPhone, I was writing text. Among the keys, I have seen arrows for moving the cursor right and left.

**How can I have these keys on iPad ?**

These would be very useful.

Why aren't these keys present on iPad ?

Comment: Was it one specific app? I've only seen right/left keys on certain apps

Comment: @Tetsujin, as of the iPhone 6 (at least), when in landscape mode, the keyboard always displays left/right keys.

Comment: @bassplayer7 ah, neat - I'm still on a 5S, so not seen that. That's likely hinting towards an answer then… not implemented, or landscape only...

Comment: @Tetsujin, I agree - it's a great feature. I noticed it when I upgraded to the 6 from the 4S so I didn't have first-hand experience that the iPhone 6 was the first to have the feature.

Comment: @bassplayer7 throw it in as an answer - I'm pretty sure you've hit the nail squarely on the head - device-dependent.

Answer (score 4):

At this point, there is no default functionality on the iPad for arrow keys. (I suppose the idea is to tap the text to position the arrow). There is a chance that there is a 3rd-party keyboard for iPad that would include arrow keys.

Those arrow keys, from what I have seen, are unique to the iPhone 6 (and Plus) while in landscape mode.

Because of the way that the iPad can be typed on (two-handed vs. two-thumbed on the iPhone), there is a chance that arrow keys will never be brought to the iPad's default keyboard.

Comment: Are arrow keys in a custom keyboard even possible?

Comment: About your last paragraph: What do you mean?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco, with iOS 9 I believe Apple brought an alternate way to edit text to the iPad. I think arrow keys could potentially pose a problem is the user accidentally taped one, and perhaps that would be accentuated while typing two handed? Also with the advent of so many 3rd party keyboards, I'm wouldn't be surprised if there is one with arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding two fingers at same time anywhere at virtual keyboard and you should be able to move cursor / marker left - right (keyboard letters become invisible in the meantime) using ios 9.x.x.